# How to save list data through sharedprefrence

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart

I am developing an E-commerce application in flutter. I want to store cart data in SharedPreference and then display it on the cart page. Here I am storing data through SharedPreference but I get an exception . I don't know about the exception, by data is saved successfully in list.

This is my function where I save data.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
final int productId;
Cart(this.productId);
static const routeName = '/cart';
@override
_CartState createState() => _CartState();
}


class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
List cart = [];
List cartProduct = [];

void initState() {
getCart();
super.initState();
}
Future getCart() async {
final response = await http.get(
    'http://192.168.10.6/flutter/cat6GetbyID.php?product_id=${widget.productId}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  cart = json.decode(response.body);
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setStringList("products", ['$cart']);
  setState(() {
    List<String> stringValue = prefs.getStringList('products') ?? [];
    cartProduct = stringValue;
  });
}
}
```

And in the code , in this way i am accessing it...

> Text(
>                                   cartProduct[index]["product"],)

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: please share the exception, a screenshot or something.